# Remove duplicate values without ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
   uuid | username | first_seen | last_seen | score
```

Before, the table used the primary key of a "player_id" column that ascended. I removed this player_id as I no longer needed it. I want to make the 'uuid' the primary key, but there's a lot of duplicates. I want to remove all these duplicates from the table, but keep the first one (based off the row number, the first row stays).

How can I do this? I've searched up everywhere, but they all show how to do it if you have a row ID column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly advocate having auto-incremented integer primary keys.  So, I would encourage you to go back.  These are useful for several reasons, such as:

- They tell you the insert order of rows.
- They are more efficient for primary keys.
- Because primary keys are clustered in MySQL, they always go at the end.

But, you don't have to follow that advice.  My recommendation would be to insert the data into a new table and reload into your desired table:

```
create temporary table tt as 
    select t.*
    from tt
    group by tt.uuid;

truncate table t;

alter table t add constraint pk_uuid primary key (uuid);

insert into t
    select * from tt;
```

Note:  I am using a (mis)feature of MySQL that allows you to `group by` one column while pulling columns not in the `group by`.  I don't like this extension, but you do not specify how to choose the particular row you want.  This will give values for the other columns from matching rows.  There are other ways to get one row per `uuid`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that right now! Also, I removed the ID because I want to prevent any duplicates for 'uuid'... Should I just make 'uuid' a unique key but still keep row number for the primary key? Oh and, since I've removed it, the database contains like, 7,000 to 23,000 rows (forgot, but in between this range), so is there a query that automatically inserts a row ID depending on the row number?

Comment: You can have an auto-incremented primary key and still declare `uuid` to be `unique`.  Your table is small, but you wouldn't assign the values, the database does for an auto incremented column.